# TERMIOS C Program to communicate with STM32F103 µC

Tags: c, usb, microcontroller, stm32, termios

I am on stm32f103c8t6 with STDP-Lib, using stm32's usb library for virtual com port and wanna to talk with the µC via termios-Pc-program. The termios program can read the data the chip is sending via USB, but when I wanna answer, the chip is not reacting on the data I send. What am I doing wrong when sending?

The termios-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef union {
  int num;
  char part[2];
} _16to8;

static void sendData(int tty, unsigned char c) {
  write(tty, &c, 1);
}

static unsigned char readData(int tty) {
  unsigned char c;
  while(read(tty, &c, 1) <= 0);
  return c;
}

static unsigned char* readALotOfData(int tty, int len) {
  unsigned char* c = NULL;
  c = calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c[i] = readData(tty);
  }
  return c;
}

static void sendCmd(int tty, char* c, size_t len) {
  unsigned char* a = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  a = calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
  memcpy(a, c, len);
  for(; i < len; i++) {
    sendData(tty, a[i]);
  }
  free(a);
  a = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct termios tio;
  int tty_fd;
  FILE* fd;

  struct stat st;

  unsigned char c;
  unsigned char* buf = NULL;
  buf = calloc(4096, sizeof(unsigned char));

  memset(&tio, 0, sizeof(tio));
  tio.c_cflag = CS8;

  tty_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
  if(tty_fd == -1) {
    printf("failed to open port\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char mode;
  if(!strcmp(argv[2], "flash")) {
    mode = 1;
    fd = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    if(fd == NULL) {
      printf("failed to open file\n");
      return 1;
    }
  } else if(!strcmp(argv[2], "erase")) {
    mode = 0;
  } else {
    printf("unknown operation mode\n");
    return 1;
  }

  cfsetospeed(&tio, B115200);
  cfsetispeed(&tio, B115200);

  tcsetattr(tty_fd, TCSANOW, &tio);

  unsigned char* id = readALotOfData(tty_fd, 20);
  printf("%s\n", id);
  if(strstr((const char*)id, "1234AABBCC1234")) {
    sendCmd(tty_fd, "4321CCBBAA4321", 14);
    printf("id verified\n");
  } else {
    printf("Could not identify device\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if(mode) {
    printf("going to flash the device\n");
    sendCmd(tty_fd, "\xF1\xA5", 2);
    stat(argv[3], &st);
    int siz = st.st_size;
    char sizR[2] = "\0";
    sizR[1] = (unsigned char)(siz & 0xFF);
    sizR[0] = (unsigned char)(siz >> 8);
    _16to8 num = {0};
    num.part[0] = sizR[0];
    num.part[1] = sizR[1];
    sendCmd(tty_fd, (char*)&num.num, 2);
    char buffer[2] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    while(fread(&buffer, 1, 4, fd)) {
      // sendCmd(tty_fd, buffer, 4);
      // printf("%s\n", readALotOfData(tty_fd, 5));
    }
  } else {
    printf("going to erase the device's memory\n");
    sendCmd(tty_fd, (char*)0xE2A5, 2);
  }

  close(tty_fd);

  return 0;
}
```

µCProgram:

```
#include "stm32f10x_conf.h"
#include "main.h"

void eraseFlashPage(uint8_t page) {
  uint32_t addr = FLASH_ADDR + 0x400 * page;
  FLASH_Unlock();
  FLASH_ClearFlag(FLASH_FLAG_PGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR | FLASH_FLAG_EOP);
  FLASH_ErasePage(addr);
  FLASH_Lock();
}

void writeFlashAddr(uint8_t page, uint16_t offset, uint32_t data) {
  uint32_t addr = FLASH_ADDR + 0x400 * page + offset;
  FLASH_Unlock();
  FLASH_ClearFlag(FLASH_FLAG_PGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR | FLASH_FLAG_EOP);
  FLASH_ProgramWord(addr, (uint32_t)data);
  FLASH_Lock();
}

uint32_t readFlashAddr(uint8_t page) {
  uint32_t addr = FLASH_ADDR + 0x400 * page;
  return *(uint32_t*)addr;
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler() {
  static int count = 0;
  if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET) {
    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);
    if(mode) {
      if(count == 2) {
        count = 0;
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_15);
      }
      count++;
    } else {
      GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_15);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  Set_System();
  Set_USBClock();
  USB_Interrupts_Config();
  USB_Init();

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
  GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable, ENABLE);
  GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioStruct;
  gpioStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15;
  gpioStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
  gpioStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpioStruct);
  GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_15, Bit_RESET);

  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE); // 200Hz -> 8Hz
  TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timStruct;
  timStruct.TIM_Prescaler = 60000;
  timStruct.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
  timStruct.TIM_Period = 50;                          // ISR at 0.125s
  timStruct.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV4;
  timStruct.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
  TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &timStruct);
  TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
  TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);

  NVIC_InitTypeDef nvicStruct;
  nvicStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
  nvicStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
  nvicStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  nvicStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&nvicStruct);

  _delay_ms(500);

  while(1) {

    mode = 0;
    Receive_length = 0;
    char bootID[64];

    for(volatile uint32_t cnt = 0; cnt < 4800 * 5000 / 4 / 25; cnt++) {
      _printf("1234AABBCC1234");
      CDC_Receive_DATA();
      if(Receive_length >= 14) {
        _gets((char*)&bootID, 14);
        if(!memcmp(bootID, "4321CCBBAA4321", 14)) {
          mode = 1;
          break;
        }
        Receive_length = 0;
      }
    }

    if(mode) {
      uint32_t opt = 0;
      _printf("operating mode?\n"); //debug
      _gets((char*)&opt, 2);

      if(opt == 0xF1A5) {
        uint32_t len = 0;
        uint32_t data = 0;
        uint16_t i = 0;

        _gets((char*)&len, 2);
        _printf("writing %d/%d bytes starting at 0x%x\n", len, (117 - START_PAGE) * 1024, FLASH_ADDR); // debug

        if(len < (117 - START_PAGE) * 1024) { // 117 or 64?
          _printf("start writing to flash\n"); //debug

          for(i = 0; i <= len / 1024; i++) {
            eraseFlashPage(i);
            _printf("erasing page %d\n", i); //debug
          }

          for(i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
            uint8_t page = i / 1024;
            _printf("i:%d page:%d offset:%d\n", i, page, i - page * 1024); // debug
            _gets((char*)&data, 4);
            writeFlashAddr(page, i - page * 1024, data);
            _printf("Page %d and 0x%x\n", page, FLASH_ADDR + 0x400 * page + i - page * 1024); // debug
          }

          _printf("done\n"); //debug

          uint32_t sp = *(uint32_t*) FLASH_ADDR;
          if((sp & 0x2FFF0000) == 0x20000000) {
            TIM_Cmd(TIM2, DISABLE);
            GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_15, Bit_RESET);
            NVIC->ICER[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            NVIC->ICER[1] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            NVIC->ICPR[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            NVIC->ICPR[1] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            PowerOff();
            pFunction jmpUser;
            uint32_t jmpAddr = *(__IO uint32_t*)(FLASH_ADDR + 4);
            jmpUser = (pFunction)jmpAddr;
            __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)FLASH_ADDR);
            jmpUser();
          }
        } else {
          _printf("not enought flash space available\n"); //debug
        }
      } else if(opt == 0xE2A5) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (117 - START_PAGE); i++) {
          eraseFlashPage(i);
          _printf("erasing page %d\n", i); //debug
        }
      }
    } else {
      uint32_t sp = *(uint32_t*) FLASH_ADDR;
      if((sp & 0x2FFF0000) == 0x20000000) {
        TIM_Cmd(TIM2, DISABLE);
        GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_15, Bit_RESET);
        NVIC->ICER[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        NVIC->ICER[1] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        NVIC->ICPR[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        NVIC->ICPR[1] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        PowerOff();
        pFunction jmpUser;
        uint32_t jmpAddr = *(__IO uint32_t*)(FLASH_ADDR + 4);
        jmpUser = (pFunction)jmpAddr;
        __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)FLASH_ADDR);
        jmpUser();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to send the identification string and then enter the operations.... A friend of me got a working program with serialport-lib usage, but I wanna use termios...

*Anyone an idea why the controller is not reacting on the sent data?*

Comment: well the union right at the beginning of your code is a problem, maybe you get lucky maybe you dont.  didnt dig into the rest.  what is the controller seeing?  what are you sending it, is it what you expected (loop it back to another uart or to the same uart).

Comment: Actually it's surprising that reading seems to work, considering what a poor job your program does for initializing & configuring the termios stuct.  Serial terminal I/O should not be functional at all.  You really need to study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)
  BTW using *"wanna"* makes you sound like a infant.